# Why is there Z-fighting when forward rendering lights?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, lighting

In my OpenGL program I noticed black pixels appearing where lights were blended together in the forward rendering algorithm. At first I ignored it until I switch Window APIs (SDL to GLFW) when it became too visually problematic.

When I disable GL_DEPTH_TEST the blacks artifacts disappear but things become transparent to lights behind them so it's not a solution. (It's how I found the potential problem)

I'm not sure what the issue is it may be the depth buffer but switching window APIs enhances the artifacts, any help?

*The pattern flickers as I move the camera*
[image: Rendered scene]

It seems the black lines/dots are isolated within each triangle

Here's where I blend lights

```
// Note: I wrapped OpenGL calls into wrapper functions but the naming convenction is still the same
gl::Clear(gl::e_ColorBufferBit | gl::e_DepthBufferBit);

mesh->Render(m_forward_ambient);
gl::Enable(gl::e_Blend);
gl::SetBlendFunc(gl::e_One, gl::e_One); // Additive blending
gl::SetDepthMask(false); // No need to write to depth buffer
gl::SetDepthFunc(gl::e_Equal); // Only draw fragments of equal depths (ignore fragments behind basically)
{
    for (word i = 0; i < m_lights.Length(); ++i)
    {
        m_active_light = m_lights[i];
        mesh->Render(m_active_light->shader); // Shaders use active light
    }
}
gl::SetDepthFunc(gl::e_Lequal); // Restore default state
gl::SetDepthMask(true);
gl::Disable(gl::e_Blend);
```

Shader Code (the shader with all the code, others implement less)

```
// Vertex
void main()
{
    // pv_matrix is projection and camera, ml_matrix is model transform
    gl_Position = pv_matrix * ml_matrix * vec4(pos, 1);
    f_pos = (ml_matrix * vec4(pos, 1)).xyz;
    f_nrm = (ml_matrix * vec4(normalize(nrm), 0)).xyz;
    f_txc = txc;
}
// Fragment
struct Light
{
    vec3 color;
    float intensity;
};
struct Attenuation
{
    float constant;
    float linear;
    float exponent;
};
struct PointLight
{
    Light light;
    Attenuation atten;
    vec3 position;
    float range;
};
struct SpotLight
{
    PointLight plight;
    vec3 direction;
    float cutoff;
};
vec4 CalculateLight(Light light, vec3 direction, vec3 normal)
{
    float diffuse_factor = dot(normal, -direction);
    vec4 diffuse_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vec4 specular_color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if (diffuse_factor > 0)
        diffuse_color = vec4(light.color, 1) * light.intensity * diffuse_factor;

    vec3 direction_to_eye = normalize(eye_pos - f_pos); // eye_pos is uniform for camera pos, f_pos is (position) attribute sent from vertex shader
    vec3 reflect_direction = normalize(reflect(direction, normal));
    float specular_factor = dot(reflect_direction, direction_to_eye); // specular calculations
    if (specular_factor > 0)
    {
        specular_factor = pow(specular_factor, specular_power);
        specular_color = vec4(light.color, 1) * specular_intensity * specular_factor;
    }

    return diffuse_color + specular_color;
}

vec4 CalculatePointLight(PointLight plight, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 light_direction = f_pos - plight.position; 
    float distance = length(light_direction); 

    if (distance > plight.range)
        return vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    light_direction = normalize(light_direction);
    vec4 color = CalculateLight(plight.light, light_direction, normal);

    float a = plight.atten.constant + (plight.atten.linear * distance) + (plight.atten.exponent * (distance * distance)) + 0.0001;

    return color / a;
}

vec4 CalculateSpotLight(SpotLight slight, vec3 normal)
{
    vec3 light_direction = normalize(f_pos - slight.plight.position);
    float spot_factor = dot(light_direction, slight.direction);

    vec4 color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    if (spot_factor > slight.cutoff)
        color = CalculatePointLight(slight.plight, normal) * (1.0 - ((1.0 - spot_factor) / (1.0 - slight.cutoff))); 

    return color; 
}

uniform SpotLight spot_light;

void main()
{
    FragColor = CalculateSpotLight(spot_light, f_nrm); // f_nrm is a (normal) attribute sent from vertex shader
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). THere is still a lot of things unknown, especially the all the vertex transformation related pats - which seem to be the most likely place for the issue, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not declare your `gl_Position` vertex shader output as `invariant`, so even if you use exactly the same formula, and bit-wise exact same inputs in both passes, your shaders aren't guaranteed to get to the exact same result. You should add proper [invariance qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_%28GLSL%29#Invariance_qualifiers) to all of the shaders in all of the passes.

Comment: Wow. That might be it. Im not a home to try it but I guess I learned a new shader info.